# Update the only column in table with using values from the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table with one column (say Name) which have two distinct values "A" & "B", now I want to update all rows of A to B and B to A.

I know we can use a third value and then achieve the update but do we have any single query solution?

Comment: This is a basic test for SQL. just search a bit to find the answer

Comment: Simply, `UPDATE YourTable
SET Name = CASE Name WHEN 'A' THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' END;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single statement, using a conditional expression:

```
update mytable
set name = case name
    when 'A' then 'B'
    when 'B' then 'A'
end
```